# Berkshelf: Cannot set unsupported config value

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

When I run berks (install, package, or simply berks) on my cookbook directory, I get the message below, saying Berks can't set the value for `ssl.verify`.

```
[jenkins@8ba245c234cb mycookbook_PR-58]$ berks
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/berkshelf-7.0.7/lib/berkshelf/cached_cookbook.rb:97: warning: already initialized constant Berkshelf::CachedCookbook::DIRNAME_REGEXP
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/berkshelf-7.0.7/lib/berkshelf/cached_cookbook.rb:97: warning: previous definition of DIRNAME_REGEXP was here
An error occurred while reading the Berksfile:

  Cannot set unsupported config value ssl.verify.
```

However, I don't even have a `~/.berkshelf/config.json` file and therefore I don't think I'm trying to set this variable anywhere. Any idea what could be wrong?

Ruby 2.4.0, Berkshelf 7.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am quoting an old answer of mine from [Berks install SSL_Connect Certification Verify failed]:

try placing the following snippet into you berksfile configuration at `~/.berkshelf/config.json`

```
{
  "ssl": {
    "verify": false
  }
}
```